# AWS Security Group Puzzle

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk

I have an AWS Security group that I use for my RDS Instances.

I also have an AWS Security group that I use for my EC2 Instances.

I have it set up so the security group for the EC2 instances is used as Ingress for the security group I use for the RDS instances.

From my EC2 instances, I can use mysql commands to access the RDS instances without a problem.

However, if I try to use a PHP Script with MySQLi to access the RDS instance, it fails to connect.

If I add the actual AWS IP address of the EC2 instance as Ingress to the RDS Security group, then the PHP script using MySQLi works fine.

Any idea why this is the case?

## More details:

1. Both RDS and EC2 security groups are on the same VPC.
2. Software is connecting fine when the EC2 private address is added with no other changes.

This is why the behavior is puzzling

Comment: Without any evidence to the contrary,  I'd chalk this up to configuration error.   Security groups are an address and port level thing - they don't know which program is making the connection.

Comment: When you say "the actual AWS IP address of the EC2 instance" are you referring to the public IP or the private IP?

Comment: I am referring to the private IP address (AWS)

Comment: Are the EC2 instance and RDS database both in the same VPC? When connecting to the database via mysql and MySQLi, how is the RDS database being referenced (eg IP address or DNS Name)?

Answer (score 0):

The typical security configuration would be:

- A Security Group on the Amazon EC2 instance (`App-SG`) with desired Inbound permissions and default 'Allow All' Outbound permissions
- A Security Group on the Amazon RDS database (`DB-SG`) that permits inbound access on port 3306 (MySQL) from `App-SG`

That is, the `DB-SG` specifically references `App-SG` in its Inbound rules.

The software on the EC2 instance should refer to the RDS database via its DNS Name, which will resolve to a private IP address (assuming that the EC2 instance and RDS database are in the same VPC).

If your configuration works with the `mysql` command on the EC2 instance, then it should also work for MySQLi access since they would both be connecting to the same destination DNS name on the same port (3306).